# put two shorts to a byte array

Tags: c#, java

I need a byte array with 4 bytes which contains 2 shorts. I have now this:

```
MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
     writer.Write((short) printscreen.Width);
     writer.Write((short) printscreen.Height);
}
byte[] bytes = str.ToArray();
```

In java I used bytebuffer. But what should I use for c#?

I send this bytes through a socket to a java server. Java code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(data);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
System.out.println(buffer.getShort());
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What are you asking?

Comment: What you have now looks good at first glance. What's the problem?

Comment: I send it through a socket to a java server and when I read one short it returns a 7. But it should return 1920.

Comment: Sounds like an endian problem

Comment: @JerKimball: If it was an endian problem, then 1920 (0x0780) would become -32761 (0x8007).

Comment: @dtb I'm sorry, it returns -32761 (I was signing the short). What is an endian problem?

Comment: You need to post the Java code.

Comment: @dtb true - in which case I'd guess that the read offset is "off" - basically, you're pulling in a zero in front of that first 0x07...hah, just read updated comments... *dance* - Jochem - you do need to post the code, but basically it means the order of your bytes are reversed.

Comment: @JochemGruter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Added the java code in the post.

Comment: @JerKimball with the clutch catch

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade Always go with yer gut. ;)

Comment: The metaproblem is you're inventing your own binary protocol. Use ASN.1 (if you need a compact encoding, although it's probably not easy to use) or something else which deals with this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation on Java's  [ByteBuffer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

> Primitive values are translated to (or from) sequences of bytes according to the buffer's current byte order, which may be retrieved and modified via the order methods. Specific byte orders are represented by instances of the ByteOrder class. **The initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN.**

From the documentation on .NET's  [BinaryWriter.Write(short) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/091b1s67.aspx):

> BinaryWriter stores this data type **in little endian format.**

Since you can't change BinaryWriter, you need to change the byte order used by the ByteBuffer:

```
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

Comment: For the future, have a look at something like *protobuf* instead of inventing your own format. There are libraries for *protobuf* that deal with these kinds of problems for you.